# AliasMatch: Match on all except if hash

Tags: angularjs, regex, ubuntu, webserver, apache2

Apache2, Ubuntu, /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf

Only number 1 needs to be aliased, number 2 does not.
I need an AliasMatch regex that omits any url with ^/#, else passes $1 into the new/path/$1

1. url.com/some_dir
2. url.com/#/some_dir

I have tried the following approaches: The first redirects both 1 and 2, because (.*). The second ones does not work at all. The third one doesn't work either, but I was trying to match on alpha-numeric chars as to omit # by default, it also does not work.

> ```
> AliasMatch "(?i)^/(.*)$" "/new/path/$1"
> AliasMatch "(?i)^((?!#).)*$" "/new/path/$1"
> AliasMatch "^/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$" "/new/path/$1"
> ```

How do I omit the url 2 while still allowing url 1 to be Aliased appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex: `^[^#]+$`

Or this one: `^.*?/[^#]+$`

They're pretty understandable.

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking to capture, though. You seem to know how to use capture groups, so you could add some. Or, in case you didn't know, if you want EVERYTHING from the regex, you can use `$0`.

Edit:

Try: `^[^/]*/([^#]+)$`

This one will chop off everything after the last slash: `^[^/]*/([^#]+)/[^#/]+$`

And this one gets the content between the first and second slash: `^[^/]*/([^#/]+)/`

Comment: I understand the majority of it; but for some reason I just cant seem to crack this problem. I am trying to capture everything after the slash in the url of example 1, if it does not begin with a #.
I tried various forms of your suggested regex, with no avail. I do think it is pretty close..

Comment: @MattBunch I've added another. It should be better and faster than the other two, and it works in my tests. (I think your regex flavor is standard enough to work with it.)

Comment: closer. :) now the issue is that, apache aliases the url, but is appending /index.html then the regex runs again and appends /index.html/index.html etc.. so it is like we need to add another condition to only grab what is in between domain.com/ [this] / [and not this] / [or this] / [etc]

I wonder if this is not the best approach to solve my issue.

(FYI apache2 is using "Perl Compatible Regular Expression vocabulary")

The regex does work when tested on this site: [link](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html)

Comment: @MattBunch I've added some more. If they don't work, please add more details/examples to the question.